# background to scroll with content and stick to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get my background to scroll with content and stick to the top of the page. My background is in a fixed position under my header.
Here's an example http://www.crunchyroll.com/

is there a way to do it in css? I'm fairly new to javascript but want to see if it can be done in css if not then I'll try it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style:

```
background-attachment: scroll;
```

This will change the background attachment to the default `fixed` to `scroll` so that it scrolls with the page rather than being stuck in one position.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6tnqynwn/) on JSFiddle.net.

Comment: Is your background image a `background-image` or is it an image that is put behind everything else?

Comment: this is how I have it as background: white url("images/Screenshota.png") no-repeat fixed 0px 91.4px;

Comment: @EdwinM How? Can you show the HTML or CSS regarding the background image?

Comment: body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: white url("images/Screenshota.png") no-repeat fixed 0px 91.4px;
    background-size: 100% 90.3%;

Comment: it scrolls but I want it to also stick to the top of the page